# VB.NET 2015 - Extract pages with different orientation

Tags: pdf, itext, extract

i found [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559380/Splitting-and-Merging-PDF-Files-in-Csharp-Using-iT) to extract pages from an pdf file using the itextsharp lib. But my document have different orientation for each page , sometimes the pagesize ist different to. But first of all i try to fix this with the page orientation. Here is my code and im out of ideas perhaps someone can tell me how i do this.

```
Public Function ExtractPdfPages(ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal TargetFile As String, ByVal IntStr As Integer, ByVal IntEnd As Integer)
    Try
        Dim impPage As PdfImportedPage = Nothing
        Dim Reader As New PdfReader(SourceFile)
        Dim PageRotation As String = ""


        Dim srcDoc As New Document(Reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(IntStr))
        Dim PdfCopyProvider As New PdfCopy(srcDoc, New System.IO.FileStream(TargetPath & "\" & TargetFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create))

        srcDoc.Open()
        For X = IntStr To IntEnd
            impPage = PdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(Reader, X)
            Dim myDocOr As Rectangle = Reader.GetPageSize(X)

            If myDocOr.Width >= myDocOr.Height Then
                PageRotation = "land"
            Else
                PageRotation = "port"
            End If
            ' --- fix orientation

            ' --- add page
            PdfCopyProvider.AddPage(impPage)

        Next

        srcDoc.Close()
        Reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try


End Function
```

Comment: Im done ;-) I found the solution to do this , Yipie

Answer (score 0):

This do it for me. For anyone else how have the same issue here the solution :

```
Public Function ExtractPdfPages(ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal TargetFile As String, ByVal IntStr As Integer, ByVal IntEnd As Integer)
    Try
        Dim impPage As PdfImportedPage = Nothing
        Dim Reader As New PdfReader(SourceFile)
        Dim PageRotation As String = ""


        Dim srcDoc As New Document(Reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(IntStr))
        Dim PdfCopyProvider As New PdfCopy(srcDoc, New System.IO.FileStream(TargetPath & "\" & TargetFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create))

        srcDoc.Open()
        For X = IntStr To IntEnd
            impPage = PdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(Reader, X)

            PdfCopyProvider.SetPageSize(New Rectangle(0.0F, 0.0F, impPage.Width, impPage.Height))

            PdfCopyProvider.AddPage(impPage)

        Next

        srcDoc.Close()
        Reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try


End Function
```

The Magic is to set the PageSize.

```
PdfCopyProvider.SetPageSize(New Rectangle(0.0F, 0.0F, impPage.Width, impPage.Height))
```